# What is happening

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I've created two classes. When I choose to retrieve the deposit or withdraw historical I can only get the dates, the values that appear are only the last one deposited.
I do not understand why it is showing only the dates.

This is the first class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;

public class AtmTime{
private String date;
private double cash, funds;
private DecimalFormat dfmt = new DecimalFormat("$,###,##0.00");

public void addFunds(double moneyIn){
    funds = funds + moneyIn;
}
public void withdrawFunds(double moneyOut){
    while(moneyOut > funds){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You have tried to withdraw " + dfmt.format(moneyOut), "Insufficient funds: " + dfmt.format(funds), JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        moneyOut = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Try again ", "Withdraw", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE));
    }
    funds = funds - moneyOut;
}
public double getFunds(){
    return funds;
}
public double getCash(){
    return cash;
}
public String getDate(){
    DateFormat dfm = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date dates = new Date();
    return dfm.format(dates);
}
}
```

And this is the second one:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;

public class AtmTimeApp{
public static void main(String []args){
    int control = 0;
    String date;
    double cash = 0;
    DecimalFormat dfmt = new DecimalFormat("$,###,##0.00");
    List<AtmTime> atmListIn = new ArrayList<AtmTime>();
    List<AtmTime> atmListOut = new ArrayList<AtmTime>();
    AtmTime atm = new AtmTime();

    while(control !=6){
        control = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"1- Funds \n 2- Add money \n 3- Withdraw \n4- Deposit history \n5- Withdraw history \n6- Exit", "Choose an option below", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE));
        if(control == 2){
            date = atm.getDate();
            double moneyIn = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Amount ", "Add Money", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE));
            atm.setDate(date);
            atm.addFunds(moneyIn);
            atmListIn.add(atm);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your new funds " + dfmt.format(atm.getFunds()), "On " + atm.getDate(), JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
        else if(control == 1){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"" + dfmt.format(atm.getFunds()), "Total in your account", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
            else if(control == 3){
                date = atm.getDate();
                double moneyOut = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Amount ", "Withdraw Money", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE));
                atm.withdrawFunds(moneyOut);
                atmListOut.add(atm);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"New funds " + dfmt.format(atm.getFunds()), "Operation Successful completed", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
                else if (control == 4){
                        for (int i=0;i<atmListIn.size();i++){
                            atm = atmListIn.get(i);
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Deposit of " + dfmt.format(atm.getCash()), "When " + atm.getDate(), JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                        }
                    }
                    else if (control == 5){
                        for (int i=0; i<atmListOut.size();i++){
                            atm = atmListOut.get(i);
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Withdraw of " + dfmt.format(atm.getCash()), "When " + atm.getDate(), JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                        }
                    }
                else if(control !=1 && control !=2 && control !=3 && control !=4 && control !=5 && control !=6)
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please choose a valid option", "Invalid number", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're repeatedly adding references to the same object:

```
List<AtmTime> atmListIn = new ArrayList<AtmTime>();
List<AtmTime> atmListOut = new ArrayList<AtmTime>();
AtmTime atm = new AtmTime();

while(control !=6){
    control = Integer.parseInt(...);
    if(control == 2){
        date = atm.getDate();
        double moneyIn = Double.parseDouble(...);
        atm.setDate(date);
        atm.addFunds(moneyIn);
        atmListIn.add(atm);
```

You should be creating a *new* object each time you want to add a record to the list, e.g.

```
List<AtmTime> atmListIn = new ArrayList<AtmTime>();
List<AtmTime> atmListOut = new ArrayList<AtmTime>();

while(control != 6) {
    control = Integer.parseInt(...);
    if(control == 2) {
        date = atm.getDate();
        double moneyIn = Double.parseDouble(...);
        AtmTime atm = new AtmTime(date, moneyIn);
        atmListIn.add(atm);
```

... and likewise elsewhere. Basically, get rid of that single `atm` variable declared outside the loop - you really *want* to be using a separate variable on each iteration, which will force you to either fetch an existing object to update/display, or create a new object to add.

Comment: Thanks man, it worked. I understood what meant. I have only one more question. When I create an object in a loop, this object will be only be accessed in this loop, right? In the for loops, to access the atm object I had to create Atm atm=atm.getDate(); Why I must write the class name Atm? Cheers

Comment: @Camus: You're declaring the *variable* within the loop - you write the class name when you declare the variable. You *could* declare the variable outside the loop, so long as you still create a new instance on each iteration of the loop... but it's generally a good idea to declare the variable in as small a scope as possible.